# Making pairwise comparisons in R but legend is missing

Tags: r, plot

I'm  tying to create a series of pairwise comparison with colored dots. The problems is that my legends is missing from the plot and therefore it's impossible to deduce what the dots mean. The following reproducible examples shows what I'm talking about:

This code produces a comparison between two dimension with a legend on the topright of the plot:

```
data1 <- data.frame(score1=rnorm(10),score2=rnorm(10))
data2 <- data.frame(score1=rnorm(10),score2=rnorm(10),score3=rnorm(10))
colors <- c(rep("red",5),rep("blue",5))

#Plot with legend
par(xpd=TRUE,mar = par()$mar + c(0,0,0,7))
plot(data2,col=colors,pch=16)l
legend("topright",legend=c("Red","Blue"),pch=16,col=c("red","blue"),inset=c(-0.4,0),)
```

But, if the number of dimension is increased, the legend is lost:

```
par(xpd=TRUE,mar = par()$mar + c(0,0,0,7))
plot(data1,col=colors,pch=16)
legend("topright",legend=c("Red","Blue"),pch=16,col=c("red","blue"),inset=c(-0.4,0),)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
#oma below sets the margins - value 10 is for the right margin
plot(data2,col=colors,pch=16, oma = c(3,3,3,10))
par(xpd=TRUE)
legend('topright',legend=c("Red","Blue"),pch=16,col=c("red","blue"))
```

You can manually add the coordinates for the legend to make it more suited to your needs.

Output:

[image]